# How to extract a file having varbinary column in u-sql script using default Extractor?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, extractor, varbinarymax

I have to Extract the varbinary column in a file. When I tried to extract it with byte[]. It show the error "Conversion Error. Column having invalid characters".

**U-SQL Script:**

> EXTRACT Id int?,createddate DateTime?,Photo byte[]
>       FROM @input
>       USING Extractors.Csv(quoting: true,nullEscape:"\N");

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Csv/Tsv/Text extractors assume that they operate on textual data, where the binary content is hex-encoded. This is necessary, since the binary otherwise could contain any of the delineation characters. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621366.aspx under byte[].

So if your photo is not hex-encoded, you would have to write your own custom extractor.

Comment: Hi Michael Rys,
Can you please give some sample or link for the custom extractor for using byte[] for varchar column.So it would help me.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't know how to handle hex column value in u-sql

Comment: And I want to preserve the same format in the data lake file too.

Comment: I don't have a custom extractor right now that handles binary data in an otherwise CSV file. There is a sample extractor that operates on JPEG images here:https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/ImageApp/Image/ImageFeatureExtractor.cs. If that still does not help you, please send me a sample file and what you would like to get out. Also, if you need to write rowset data back without hex encoding, you will need a custom outputter (some sample outputters are on the GitHub repository as well).

Comment: Already I am having the sql data as a file in Data Lake. From there i want to extract and do some filtering things using u-sql and that will place in other folder.

Comment: I having varbinary column along with other columns, so I don't know how to use custom extractor for fetching all the column values in a row.

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that your column separation does not appear inside your binary value? If you can provide me with a sample input file, we can probably generate an extractor. You can reach me at usql at microsoft dot com.

Comment: I have converted the varbinary column into varchar data type while fetching from the SQL using 
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5000), varbinarycolumn, 1).

Comment: CONVERT does not hex-encode in TSQL as far as I remember. So you may end up having any of the column or row separators appear inside the string. Did you get it to work?